# Base64 and binary streams between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, scala, base64

I feel like the answer is obvious but suppose I have the following in C#

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        // Write some floats, bytes, and uints
        // Convert.ToBase64String this stuff from ms.ToArray
    }
}
```

and the following in Java (ok it's Scala but using Java libraries):

```
val byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val outStream = new DataOutputStream(byteStream)
// Write some floats, bytes, and longs where the uints were using 
// writeFloat, writeByte, and writeLong. .NET has an overloaded 
// function that takes whatever. 
// Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString byteStream.toByteArray
```

I get completely different base 64 strings. What are they doing different here? I need the Java output to match the .NET output. I assume its some sort of byte ordering issue but I haven't had any luck using `ByteBuffer` to correct this.

Java:

> PczMzT3MzM0/gAAAPczMzQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD3MzM0/gAAAAQAAAABRn8XzAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQ==

C# (with unknown = signs as we chop them off for reasons) :

> zczMPc3MzD0AAIA/zczMPQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM3MzD0AAIA/AfPFn1EBAAAAAQAAAA

I really feel as though it is byte ordering which is why I tried using `ByteBuffer` in the Java code, order method, to change the ordering but I did not have success.

For further clarity the Java code is running on x86_64 CentOS Java 7 and the .NET is on x86_64 Windows Server 2008 .NET 4.These values are coming from Protobuf objects so they should be pretty cross platform I would think. Numerically the data is identical and consistent regardless of what I put in at least when I write at least these three data types. The only significant difference is the lack of an unsigned type in Java and perhaps there is a binary representation difference which is where I was initially trying to resolve but I do not seem to be able to figure it out.

As I have said. Using another format is not an option. I need the binary data written from java and then base 64 encoded to result in the same results as .NET. Serialization choices are not an option. This has to be it. I need a resource that will aid in bringing this together whether that means binary manipulation of byte data or not. I need some explanation in the datatypes and as I have searched significantly and not found a resource explaining how to do this or what the real differences are so I can implement a solution I decided to ask here.

Comment: I suggest you provide some sample input and output that demonstrates the differences.

Comment: What are you trying to encode? A string?

Comment: Binary serialization is rarely magically work cross platforms (and even cross versions of the same platform). You need to carefully investigate how each writes particular types and make sure they match - i.e. .Net uses compressed int format for integer types...

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro Its a byte array. I do however need that byte array as a string for what its used for downstream.

Comment: Please give a simple example which reproduces this bug - ideally one that shows how you write and read the data.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is definitely correct however I have now spent about 5 hours attempting many different things and haven't quite nailed it down so I thought it was time to ask for help from someone that may have encountered this.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are using Java `long` (8 bytes) as the equivalent of .NET's `uint` type (4 bytes)?  That could never work.  You need to use equivalent type sizes.

Comment: @sstan I suspected this at one point to be a problem as well however the output is not the same even if writing the longs casted to ints.

Comment: As you seem to already be aware of, Java does not have unsigned Integer. I'm not sure how *"where the uints were using writeFloat, writeByte, and writeLong"* addresses that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that C#'s `BinaryWriter` writes the data type's low bytes first, where as Java's `DataOutputStream` writes the high bytes first.

Also, when you write a .NET unsigned integer, that writes 4 bytes. But when you write a Java `long`, it writes 8 bytes.  So that's another difference right there.

But fixing them to match is actually not that hard once you understand the differences.  Here are 2 code snippets, one in C#, and the other in Java that encode the same information and output the same `Base64`-encoded string.  In my case, I chose to override how Java writes the `float`s and `long`s.

**.NET code sample**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
        {
            // floats
            bw.Write(-456.678f);
            bw.Write(0f);
            bw.Write(float.MaxValue);

            // bytes
            bw.Write((byte)0);
            bw.Write((byte)120);
            bw.Write((byte)255);

            // uints
            bw.Write(0U);
            bw.Write(65000U);
            bw.Write(4294967295U);
        }

        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(base64String);
    }
}
```

**Java code sample**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        try (DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(byteStream)) {
            // floats
            writeFloat(-456.678f, outStream);
            writeFloat(0f, outStream);
            writeFloat(Float.MAX_VALUE, outStream);

            // bytes
            outStream.writeByte(0);
            outStream.writeByte(120);
            outStream.writeByte(255);

            // longs (uints)
            writeUint(0L, outStream);
            writeUint(65000L, outStream);
            writeUint(4294967295L, outStream);
        }

        String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteStream.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(base64String);
    }
}

private static void writeFloat(float f, DataOutputStream stream) throws Exception {
    int val = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    stream.writeByte(val & 0xFF);
    stream.writeByte((val >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    stream.writeByte((val >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    stream.writeByte((val >>> 24) & 0xFF);
}

private static void writeUint(long val, DataOutputStream stream) throws Exception {
    stream.writeByte((int) (val & 0xFF));
    stream.writeByte((int) ((val >>> 8) & 0xFF));
    stream.writeByte((int) ((val >>> 16) & 0xFF));
    stream.writeByte((int) ((val >>> 24) & 0xFF));
}
```

**Output for both samples**

> yVbkwwAAAAD//39/AHj/AAAAAOj9AAD/////

Make sure you test edge cases with the `float` type and make adjustments where necessary. If it matters to you, I expect funny values like `NaN` to cause differences, but maybe you don't care about that.  Otherwise, I expect that it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for a real answer. I kind of was thinking I would have to do something like what you have here but wasn't quite sure with there to start. Thanks.

Comment: So, this actually doesn't seem to produce the same output in practice. I feel like its close but its definitely not producing the same values. 

yVbkwwAAAAD//39/AHj/AAAAAOj9AAD///// vs /////wAA/egAAAAA/3gAf3///wAAAADD5FbJ

They don't look similar enough to even be reverse ordered and reversing the write shows that.

Comment: Do you mind trying the Java version on a Windows machine (which is how I tested it), and see if it gives the same result there?  I'm curious to see the problem is OS specific.  Though when I looked at the Java source code, it didn't seem to be the case.  (I'm assuming that the Java version of the code is the one that produced `/////wAA/egAAAAA/3gAf3///wAAAADD5FbJ`, right?)

Comment: Actually, I lied. It is actually exactly as you claim. You have it totally nailed.

Comment: Thanks again for the fantastic work

Comment: One thing I was actually looking for out of this question was a sort of compilation of these sort of differences between .NET and the JVM. I can almost be certain I will encounter another similar situation in the future as I'm migrating a code base that requires backwards compatibility. Is there a compilation that you know of?

Comment: Not that I know of.  And even if you find one, it would probably go out of date pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

How to implement cross-platform binary communication:

- define exact byte format
- implement in each platform

Frequently you can simplify both steps by using off-the-shelf protocol that is close to your needs (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) and supported on one or all platforms you are interested in.

Note that generally basic binary serialization types in a given language/framework are targeting strictly that language/framework (and often particular version) as it frequently gives speed/size benefit and there is no well accepted standard on "binary object representation".

Alternative approach is to use well defined text formats like JSON/XML as suggested in other answer.

Some possible technical differences between binary formats:

- serialization of integer types can differ by byte order/possible alternative representation (like compressed int in .Net)
- size of boolean and enumeration types could be different
- arrays/strings can use different types to represent length
- padding may be added by some binary represenations
- strings can be Utf8, Utf-16, or any other specified/unspecified encoding with or without trailing 0.

Comment: It has to be base64 encoded data and it must be equivalent. Is there a resource that would help identify a path to bring a Java int/long/float/double to a format equivalent to a .NET value on a byte level?

Comment: @Rig Look at the source and see how it is done in .Net and match that code in Java... Personally I'd just write bytes myself in both only 4 types involved.

Answer (score 1):

Different platforms have different binary representations. If you want to match base64 strings you should use json or xml serialization. Json or xml providing cross platform.

Editted: Don't missunderstand me: Base64 is standard encoding  algorithm. It gives the same output for the same data. I mean byte array might be different.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. They must be base64 and they must match.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  Base64 can be completely cross-platform.

Comment: As was said before if the same data is correctly encoded to Base64 does not matter if it's C/C#/Java/PHP/JavaScript/VB.net this is like an encryption method or hashing method if it's done correctly they must match

Comment: If you using binary serialize to in custom type how it can be match?

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro of course base64 is standart encryption algorithm. I mean byte array can be different.

Comment: @umutözkan They should be able to be byte equivalent. Interop is a thing and platforms of all types need to be handle the same data even if it takes additional steps.

Comment: `BinaryWriter` is a .Net specific class and its output doesn't have to be the equal to a similar class in java so I don't think this answer is wrong in what it wants to say.  So to offset the -1's . +1

Comment: @Eser No but they do the same function. They take data and write out their binary representation on their platform. This "answer" does not answer the question which is how do you make them represent the data equally as should be entirely possible. At best its a comment so the downvotes are totally appropriate as it does not meet SO's guidelines for a good answer.

Comment: @Rig `They take data and write out their binary representation` What is the  binary represantation of `1`. `00000001H` or `01000000H` ? it depends of the endianness of the platform. How would you write a string as binary.? Null ending string or length-prefixed string? which encoding? So the suggestions in this answer is correct. Use xml or Json.

Comment: @Eser and that's the whole point of the question. Which this "answer" does not even attempt to answer.

Comment: @Rig and this answer said "use xml, and json". I agree it is a poor answer but it is correct.

Comment: @Rig Answer correctly suggest to use existing well supported cross-platform standards JSON or XML to represent data. While it may not be what you want it still is valid option for your question in current form. Note that I believe your actual question is "how to write binary serialization to be byte-compatible between Java and .Net" (while currently it talks about Base64 which is likely unrelated to your problem).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That is not an options for this use case. If it was I would not be asking this question and I would have done it. Not every application is something one gets to write from scratch or make wide sweeping changes at will.

Comment: @Rig then create your own binary writer that would create the same byte array on all platforms and use it. Base64 encoding is not related to to your problem...

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption algorithm. It's an *encoding* algorithm. If you base64 something and think it's encrypted, you're doing to have a bad time

Comment: @ArneClaassen  thanks for correction. Right word is encoding. I just make a writing mistake.